# Creating Navigation Drawer with Image in header in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, Button, TextInput, View, StyleSheet, Text, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerItems, DrawerNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

export default class Home extends Component {

const DrawerContent = (props) => (
  <View>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#f50057',
        height: 140,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 30 }}>
        Header
      </Text>
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />
  </View>
)

const Navigation = DrawerNavigator({
  // ... your screens
   Home:{ 
      screen: HomeScreen,
   },
   Settings: {
      screen: SettingsScreen,
   },

}, {
  // define customComponent here
  contentComponent: DrawerContent,
})


  render() {

    return (
        <View>
        <Text>Welcome To Home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am designing a screen which will be a home screen for my app. This screen will have navigation drawer like in Android and the drawer header will contain an image and a text label inside it and below that there will be drawer items from which i will navigate to a different screen. I have tried to achieve this using the above code but it doesn't work. Can you tell me where i am wrong? How can i achieve my target? I am a newbie to react native so i please make my concepts clear

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your **DrawerContent** with the following code and check if it works.

```
const DrawerContent = (props) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingBottom: 20 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 80, backgroundColor: '#f50057'}}>
            <Image style={{ width: 181, height: 132}} source={images.logo} />
        </View>
          <Text style={{ color: '#000', fontSize: 30 }}>Header</Text>
      </View>
      <DrawerItems {...props}/>
    </SafeAreaView>
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

First create `Drawer Component`

```
export default class DrawerComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
            <Image
              style={{ margin: 15 }}
              source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}

            />
          </View>
          <DrawerItems {...this.props} />
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

and import the component in your `Home.js`

```
import DrawerComponent from "./path/to/drawerComponent";
```

**Please note :** ScrollView is necessary for the case when you have more items to show *ex: 7+ items* (with margins in style prop) and also when screen height is small